# Finding $x-\frac{1}{x}$, given $x^3 - \frac{1}{x^3} = 108+76\sqrt{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x^3 - \dfrac{1}{x^3} = 108+76\sqrt{2}$, find the value of $x-\dfrac{1}{x}$.

Here's what I've tried so far.

$$\begin{align}
\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^3&=x^3-\dfrac{1}{x^3}-3\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right) \\
\rightarrow \quad \left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^3&=108+76\sqrt{2}-3\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right) \\u:=x-\dfrac{1}{x} \quad\rightarrow \quad u^3+3u-108-76\sqrt{2}&=0
\end{align}$$

Got stuck here since I didn't know how to solve this cubic equation.

I also tried factorizing $x^3-\dfrac{1}{x^3}$.

$$\begin{align}x^3-\dfrac{1}{x^3}&=\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}+1\right) \\
&= \left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}+2-1^2\right) \\
&= \left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\left(\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2-1^2\right) \\
&= \left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}+1\right)\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}-1\right)
\end{align}$$

Again, I didn't know what I could do with this.

Comment: Hint. $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=(x-y)^3-3xy(x-y)$.

Comment: You should be able to figure this out with  the hints. However, MSE expects that you show your own efforts. This is not a portal to dump questions.

Comment: @Andreas ok, adding what I've tried so far.

Comment: @RDK, what after that? I've already tried doing this to no avail, although this could be something I missed.

Comment: Alright, you may think this is not worth doing because of $xy$. Then, try to "eliminate" $xy$. What's $y$ which makes $xy=1$? (With a bit of calculus, you can easily know the critical point, but with precalculus, just try solving this.)

Comment: Try making the variable substitution $u = x^3$, solve for $u$, and take the cube root.

Comment: @Dan which method are you referring to, the first or second one?

Comment: @RDK $y = \frac{1}{x}$. but I'm still getting a cubic, namely $u^3+3u-108-76\sqrt{2}=0$

Comment: @avighnac Nice. Now, let's think about a remainder theorem in $\Bbb Q$. This will help you solve this. (Or, just use Cubic Formula, which exactly tells you the answer.)

Comment: Cubic Formula with $ax^3+cx+d=0$: $x=\sqrt[3]{\left( - \frac d {2a} \right)+\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{4a^2}+\frac{c^3}{27a^3}}} + \sqrt[3]{\left( -\frac {d}{2a} \right)-\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{4a^2}+\frac{c^3}{27a^3}}}$

Comment: @RDK you mean $u$ is probably a multiple of $\sqrt{2}$? It’d really help if add a part to your answer solving this using the remainder theorem. Also, using the cubic formula poses the problem of the ‘nested cube root’.

Comment: @RDK, actually, if $c=\pm 3$, there’s an even simpler cubic formula. $x^3+3x=c : x= \sqrt[3]{\frac{c\pm \sqrt{c^2+4}}{2}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{c\pm \sqrt{c^2+4}}}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solve for $x$ first. You can use the quadratic formula.

$$x^3 - \frac1{x^3} = 108 + 76\sqrt2 \implies x^6 - (108+76\sqrt2)x^3 - 1 = 0$$

$$\implies x^3 = \frac{108+76\sqrt2 \pm \sqrt{(108+76\sqrt2)^2 + 4}}2 = 54 + 38\sqrt2 + 3\sqrt{645 + 456 \sqrt2}$$

$$\implies x = \sqrt[3]{54 + 38\sqrt2 + 3\sqrt{645 + 456 \sqrt2}} = \frac{3+2\sqrt2}2 + \frac12 \sqrt{21 + 12\sqrt2}$$

The hardest part is de-nesting the cube root (see below). Otherwise take [WA at its word](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cuberoot%2854+%2B+38sqrt2+%2B+3+sqrt%28645+%2B+456+sqrt2%29%29).

It follows that

$$\frac1x = \frac2{3 + 2\sqrt2 + \sqrt{21 + 12\sqrt2}} = -\frac{3+2\sqrt2}2 + \frac12 \sqrt{21 + 12\sqrt2}$$

and you can easily find $x-\frac1x$ from here.

---

**De-nesting the cube root**

Observe that

$$645 + 456 \sqrt2 = (21 + 12\sqrt2) (17 + 12\sqrt2) = (21 + 12\sqrt2) (3 + 2\sqrt2)^2 \\
\implies x^3 = 54 + 38\sqrt2 + 9\sqrt{21+12\sqrt2} + 6\sqrt2\sqrt{21+12\sqrt2}$$

Suppose we can decompose the cube root into the form

$$x = a + b \sqrt2 + c \sqrt{21+12\sqrt2}$$

where $a,b,c\in\Bbb Q$.

Taking cubes on both sides and matching up coefficients, we get the system of equations

$$\begin{cases}
a^3 + 6 a b^2 + 63 a c^2 + 72 b c^2 = 54 \\
2b^3 + 3 a^2 b + 36 a c^2 + 63 b c^2 = 38 \\
7c^3 + a^2 c + 2 b^2 c = 3 \\
2c^3 + a b c = 1
\end{cases}$$

Solving the last equation for $c^2 = 3ab-a^2-2b^2$ and substituting that into the first two equations yields yet another system,

$$\begin{cases}
-62a^3 + 117a^2b + 96ab^2 - 144b^3 = 54 \\
-36a^3 + 48a^2b + 117 ab^2 - 124b^3 = 38
\end{cases}$$

Since both polynomials are [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) with degree $3$, suppose that $a,b$ are proportional. Let $b=ka$ where $k\in\Bbb Q$, so we have

$$\begin{cases}
a^3(-62 + 117k + 96k^2 - 144k^3) = 54 \\
a^3(-36 + 48k + 117k^2 - 124k^3) = 38
\end{cases}$$

Eliminate $a^3$ by division to get a cubic equation in $k$.

$$\frac{a^3(-62 + 117k + 96k^2 - 144k^3)}{a^3(-36 + 48k + 117k^2 - 124k^3)} = \frac{27}{19} \implies 612k^3 - 1335k^2 + 927k - 206 = 0$$

Now apply the rational root theorem. If you start with the smallest divisors of $612$ and $206$, you'll soon find $k=\frac23$ (and we can show this is the only rational solution for $k$). It follows that

$$b=\frac23a \implies 16a^3 = 54 \implies a = \frac32 \implies b = 1 \implies c = \frac12$$

Comment: Wow. You did very difficult computations.

Comment: Thank you, but I wouldn’t be able to decompose that cube root without WA!

Comment: In the first part of ‘decomposing the cube root’, how did you manage to make that observation? Or was it just pure luck/intuition

Comment: The second half of this answer is more an attempt at explaining how WA is getting its result. One could instead assume a decomposition of the form $a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt{645+456\sqrt2}+d\sqrt2\sqrt{645+456\sqrt2}$ but then the system of equations that follows is a bit more complicated (again with a single solution over the rationals, namely $(a,b,c,d)=\left(\frac32,1,\frac32,-1\right)$).

Comment: @user170231 why would you have the ‘d’ term when the original cube root doesn’t have it?

Comment: My perhaps unsatisfying answer is that the algebra just works out that way. Consider a simpler example like$$(a + b\sqrt s + c\sqrt t + d\sqrt s\sqrt t)^2 = \\ a^2 + b^2s + c^2t + d^2st + (2ab+2cdt)\sqrt s + (2ac+2bds)\sqrt t + (2ad + 2bc) \sqrt s\sqrt t$$Now make any choice of $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Q$ such that $ad+bc=0$, and pick any two $s,t\in\Bbb N$ that are not perfect squares. For example, choosing $(a,b,c,d)=(1,1,-1,1)$ and $(s,t)=(3,5)$ gives$$1+\sqrt3-\sqrt5+\sqrt{15}=\sqrt{24-8\sqrt3+4\sqrt5}$$despite the nested form not explicitly involving $\sqrt{15}$.

Comment: And in fact in an earlier version of this answer, I had assumed$$x = a + b \sqrt2 + c \sqrt{21+12\sqrt2} + d\sqrt2\sqrt{21+12\sqrt2}$$but since it turned out $d=0$, I was previously under the same wrong impression that the $\sqrt s\sqrt t$ term was not needed in the denested form.

Answer (score 6):

I thought it might be helpful with answering now.

\begin{align}
\newcommand{w}{\omega}
& x^3-\frac{1}{x^3}=108+76\sqrt{2}. \\
& 108+76\sqrt{2} = \left(x-\frac 1 x\right)\left(x^2+1+\frac 1 {x^2}\right) \\
& = \left(x-\frac 1 x \right)^3+3x\cdot \frac 1 x \left(x-\frac 1 x\right). \\
\ \\
& u^3+3u=108+76\sqrt{2}. \\
& 108+76\sqrt{2}= 4(27+19\sqrt{2})=4(5+3\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{2})^2. \\
& (5+3\sqrt{2})^2+3=46+30\sqrt{2} \neq 12+8\sqrt{2}. \\
& \vdots \\
& (3+2\sqrt{2})^2+3=20+12\sqrt{2}=4(5+3\sqrt{2}). \\
\therefore \; & u=3+2\sqrt{2}.
\end{align}

Substituting $x-\dfrac 1 x=3+2\sqrt{2}$, it works.

Comment: Wow, that’s amazing. Any tips on how to factor $a + b\sqrt{c}$, like you did here?

Comment: How would you know that you need to check integers for the rational an irrational part?

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$(x - \frac{1}{x})^3 = x^3 - 3x + \frac{3}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3}$$
$$(x - \frac{1}{x})^3 = x^3 - \frac{1}{x^3} - 3(x - \frac{1}{x})$$
$$x^3 - \frac{1}{x^3} = (x - \frac{1}{x})^3 + 3(x - \frac{1}{x})$$

So if you let $t = x - \frac{1}{x}$ (the value that you're ultimately planning to solve for), then your equation becomes:

$$t^3 + 3t = 108 + 76\sqrt{2}$$

This is a “depressed” cubic equation that you *could* solve with Cardano's Formula, but that gives you some ugly nested radicals.  So instead, I'm going another route, by finding an equivalent polynomial equation with integer coefficients.

$$(t^3 + 3t - 108)^2 = (76\sqrt{2})^2$$
$$t^6 + 3t^4 - 108t^3 + 3t^4 + 9t^2 - 324t - 108t^3 - 324t + 11664 = 11552$$
$$t^6 + 6t^4 - 216t^3 + 9t^2 - 648t + 112 = 0$$

There's no general formula for a sixth-degree polynomial.  And the Rational Root Theorem fails to provide us with any linear factors.  But it turns out that a *quadratic* factor exists.

$$(t^2 - 6 t + 1) (t^4 + 6 t^3 + 41 t^2 + 24 t + 112) = 0$$

Solving the quadratic gives $t = 3 \pm 2\sqrt{2}$.  [Solving the remaining quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation) gives 4 complex solutions:

$$t = -\frac{3}{2} + \sqrt{2} \pm \frac{3}{2} i \sqrt{7 - 4 \sqrt{2}}$$
$$t = -\frac{3}{2} - \sqrt{2} \pm \frac{3}{2} i \sqrt{7 + 4 \sqrt{2}}$$

But of these 6 roots, it turns out that only one of them is a valid solution to the original equation.

$$t = \boxed{3 + 2\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: nice! Although it's far from obvious to spot the quadratic factor.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion to get an answer systematically - though not fully analytic.

Others have already noted that we need to solve for the desired $u = x- \frac{1}{x}$ in $$f(u) = u^3+3u- 108- 76\sqrt{2} = 0$$
Now observe that any expression of the form $y = a + b \sqrt{2}$, when taken to an integer power, reproduces this form, i.e. $y^n = a_n + b_n \sqrt{2}$. Since the constant part in $f(u)$ is also of this form,  we can write $u = a + b \sqrt{2}$, which gives
$$f(u) = a^3 +  6 a b^2 + 3 a -108 + \sqrt{2} (3 a^2 b +2  b^3 + 3  b - 76)   = 0 $$
This enables us to solve for the rational and the irrational parts separately, i.e.
$$a^3 +  6 a b^2 + 3 a -108  = 0\\
3 a^2 b +2  b^3 + 3  b - 76   = 0 $$
where $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers. Note that it is **not** clear beforehand whether $a$ and $b$ are integers, as other answers have tested some integer combinations.

Now this is again two coupled third-degree equations so one might ask what has been won (maybe one of you has a nice idea how to solve this analytically).

I introduce now a  way to manipulate these equations to come up with an iterative procedure with works without any knowledge or presupposition of the nature of  $a$ and $b$. Also, it does not need any roots (of quadratic or cubic equations) which have been used earlier but which can become cumbersome.

Writing equivalently
$$a^2 +  6  b^2 + 3 -\frac{108}{a}  = 0\\
3 a^2  +2  b^2 + 3   - \frac{76}{b}   = 0 $$
allows to isolate the terms with $a^2$ and $b^2$ by weighted adding, which gives

$$4 a^2 + 54/a + 3 = 114/b \\
8 b^2 + 38/b + 3 = 162/a$$
Now let $A = 1/a$ and $B = 1/b$ to end with
$$B = \frac{9 A}{19} + \frac{1}{38} + \frac{2}{57 A^2} \\
 A = \frac{19 B}{81} + \frac{1}{54} + \frac{4}{81 B^2}$$
One can make this an iterative pair of equations; start with some $A$, obtain directly $B$ from the first equation, plug into the second and obtain a new $A$, repeat ...

Both equations are of  the same functional form.
Since there must be a solution, the first one should fall faster with $A$ then the second one with $B$, so this iteration should converge.  Here are some values which are obtained when starting with $A=1$:

$$A=1 , B = 0.535, A = 0.3165, B = 0.526, A = 0.320, B = 0.520, A = 0.323, \cdots $$

Convergence is not very fast, but letting  this go for a while leads to values which are approximating $$A=\frac13 , B = \frac12$$ and indeed one can check that this solves the equations.

So the result is $u = 3 + 2 \sqrt{2}$, q.e.d. $\qquad  \Box$

Comment: Hey, at the beginning of your answer, you mention that you need to solve for $u=x+\frac{1}{x}$, but that cubic equation only works if u is the conjugate of what you’ve assumed it to be.

Comment: @avighnac Sorry, writing error -> corrected. Thank you for mentioning!

Answer (score 2):

> $u^3+3u=108+76\sqrt{2}$

A few posts here assumed $u = a + b\sqrt{2}$, then search for rational $(a, b)$

Let "slope", $\displaystyle \;m_1 = b/a$

$\displaystyle u^2 = (a^2+2b^2) \;+\; (2ab)\,\sqrt{2}\qquad\; →m_2 = \frac{2\,m_1}{1+2\,m_1^2}$

Note that $m_2$ has same sign as $\displaystyle m_1 \quad →m_∞ = \frac{sgn(m1)}{\sqrt{2}}$

Slope of RHS = $\displaystyle \frac{76}{108} ≈ 0.7037 
\;<\; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ≈ 0.7071$

$u^3 ≈ RHS,\;m_1$ likely convergent of RHS slope.

```
C:\>spigot -C 76/108
0/1
1/1
2/3
5/7
7/10
19/27
```

Convergent 2/3 work! Upon checking, $(b,a) = (2,3)$, not just the ratio.

$u^3 + 3u = (99+70\sqrt{2}) + 3×(3+2\sqrt{2}) = 108+76\sqrt{2}$

Comment: (108+76√2)^(1/3) ≈ 6.00, which is already close to (3+2√2) ≈ 5.83.

Comment: cbrt(x+y√D) = a+b√D, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4621416