# Simplifying $x-\dfrac1x$, where $x = \sqrt[3]{54+38\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt{645+456\sqrt{2}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question arises from this question: [How do I solve for $x-\frac{1}{x}$ here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555856/how-do-i-solve-for-x-frac1x-here)

One of the answers recommends I use the quadratic formula to solve for $u$, and cube root that to get $x$. I'm getting
$$x = \sqrt[3]{54+38\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt{645+456\sqrt{2}}}$$ I don't really need the value of x: but I do need the value of $x-\dfrac{1}{x}$. So really, the radical I need to simplify is this:

$$\sqrt[3]{54+38\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt{645+456\sqrt{2}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{54+38\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt{645+456\sqrt{2}}}}$$

Comment: This is just $3+2 \sqrt{2}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yeah, it is! Could you post an answer w/ your working and thought process?

Comment: Just mental calculation ! (joke)

Comment: My first try, which might not succeed, would be $$\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} - 2.$$  My second try, which also might not succeed, would be $$\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^3 = x^3 - \frac{1}{x^3} - 3\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right).$$

Comment: @user2661923 you mean substitute $x$ in the right part for both cases?

Comment: @avighnac No, I mean that you apparently have a value for both $~x~$ and $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}.~$  I suggest using both values.

Comment: @user2661923 ah, okay.